# Can you train the Scrapely Scraper on multiple urls?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapely

I wanted to know if it is possible to train the Scrapely Scraper multiple times to fit on more websites. So the code below trains the scraper on one website:

```
s = Scraper()

url_sample = dataset[0]["sample"]    # some url
targets = dataset[0]["targets"]      # some targets, ie.: {"name": "max", "age": "27}
s.train(url_sample, targets)
```

But is this also possible?:

```
s = Scraper()

for idx in range(len(dataset)):
    url_sample = dataset[idx]["sample"]
    targets = dataset[idx]["targets"]
    s.train(url_sample, targets)
```

Thanks in advance :)